# Do my Forget-me-nots need more sunlight?

Tags: seedlings

I planted them two weeks ago, a week later they germinated. Although two days ago I noticed that one was drooping and that they were a dull green. I'm not sure if they need more sunlight; I was thinking about hanging the pot and tilting it to phase the sunlight more but I'm not if that is what they need.

Comment: Can you add a photo of the pot and the forget-me-nots please?